# Azure Data Factory - share Integration Runtime on different Resource Groups

Tags: authorization, azure-data-factory

In an Azure Data Factory (ADF_1) from a Resource Group (RS_1), I need to share a self-hosted IntegrationRuntime from ADF_1 (where this IntegrationRuntime resides and run well) into ADF_2, located in another Resource Group (RS_2).

For sharing process the first step is:
**"1.Grant permission to the Data Factory in which you would like to reference this IR (shared)"**

When I'm trying to grant permission from UI, I receive the error:

"*The client 'xxx@yyy.com' with object id 'xxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/...' or the scope is invalid."*

My role is '**Contributor**' on both Resource Groups (RS_1 & RS_2)

Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Contributor` role is not enough to add the role assignments(i.e. grant permission in this case), to do this, you need the `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` action permission as mentioned in the error message.

To solve the issue, your account needs the role which has `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` permission e.g. [**User Access Administrator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) or [**Owner**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#owner).

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed this was the issue